# How to monitor HTTP(S) traffic / URLs in Android?

Tags: android

I'm interested in whether there is a way to monitor HTTP(S) traffic on an Android phone? What I would like to do is to be able to retrieve all URLs that have been accessed on the phone's browser. I thought that there would be a browser intent for that, but have not seen anything - given I'm green, maybe I just did not know where to look?

I followed the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent), but it works only for hyperlinks which were clicked by the user, however I need to catch all URLs - including the ones typed in by the user. Basically I need to know about every single URL that was opened in the web browser.

Can I register some kind of a handler with the browser?

Is something like that feasible at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure how (or if) you can use this (never used it myself), but it might be worth a look: [Browser.getAllVisitedUrls(ContentResolver cr)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#getAllVisitedUrls%28android.content.ContentResolver%29)

Comment: I thought about it, but it's unreliable, I think - I would have to poll it constantly and the user may be able to clear the browser history/cache just in time before my service polls it for data. There should be a better way.

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any way to spy on the user.

Comment: There should, with the user's knowledge and upon their request. I have a use for this, I'm just wondering about what's possible from the technical standpoint.

Comment: If you're worried about the user clearing the history before your application accesses it, just tell him not to.

Comment: @Felix, do you see what Pawel was talking about: `from the technical standpoint`. Yes, and do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we could learn solutions from PC platform:

- **Application Level**: set a global HTTP proxy
- **Linux Level**: tcpdump or WireShark?
- **Modify Android Source**: add your monitor module into browser or network protocol stack

Actually, I also want to solve this problem **efficiently**.

@Pawel Krakowiak, have u got a valid method now? Please communicate with me.

Comment: No, I don't. No was able to answer this question for 1.5 year. :)

Comment: I think the best solution is to set a global HTTP proxy.

Comment: @HackNone Could you please share how to set a global http proxy in application level?