# how to give alert to the browser from application?

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android. When the user try to open a *.ics mail attachment files from the browser, I have to give an alert message. Is it possible to give an alert to the browser from my application? Please Guide me to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it myself but you can try intercepting links as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app).