# Android Installation of APK via Browser Link

Tags: android, installation, apk

I want to create a web page that has two links.  One that downloads the agent itself (which is pretty easy, just linking to the APK file with the appropriate MIME types set), and the other to start the install process for the APK downloaded in step one.

I know they can just pull down the bar and click on it, but that can be confusing for users (especially in the overall process we are trying to create).  Is there a special URI I can use to start the installation, sort of like the market link of "market://"?

Also, is there a way to get meta-data surrounding where the APK was actually installed from? For example, if the link for the APK is "http://company.com/setting=123", that I can pull in the "setting=123" from the URL?  I suspect not, but I figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add url interceptors to your app like it's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1609573/119895) but AFAIK there is no way to do what you are asking.

Comment: My research has determined the same thing. Oh well, for now the users will just have to pull down the bar :). Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

check open2go.com
it may help you.

example here

http://open2go.com/http://m.getjar.com/mobile/49757/angry-birds-seasons/

open2go.com/ + url 
  market: schema works to.