# Android Custom URL to open App like in iOS

Tags: android, html, ios

I can add a link to, for example, 'navigon://' on a website that, in iOS devices, will open up the Navigon app if it is installed.

Is there a similar simple method to open an app from a website (assuming it's installed) in Android?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android

Comment: Hi @MaFt I have the same problem like you Did you find solution?

Comment: I have done this in my android app, using intent filter, now the problem is the url link using in email is redirected to another one that i need. And the initial link does not get detected. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Hope this will help you or someone else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781149/app-link-not-working-for-facebook-on-android/40781465#40781465

Answer (score 21):

Android deep linking: Add an intent filter to your manifest

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos”
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />
    -->
</intent-filter>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: How do I get the complete URL out of the same (I am trying to get an argument from the URI)

Comment: You may use  intent.getDataString()  to get complete url. Reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/2641380

Comment: This only works with http/https protocol. It doesn't work with custom protocol , such as navigon:// as in @Tim Castelijns's question

Comment: ` <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->` is very very important, I was trying url apit-testing in postman and wondering why same url it's not opening in android, for stripe-terminal-android-app.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) in Android. Check out the Category specially.

Comment: Thanks but that refers to coding an app using the Android SDK. I need a way to open an app from a web page 'a' link eg <a href="navigon://">Open Navigon</a> would open Navigon app if installed on an iOS device.

Comment: Ohh sure there are ways, I'll let you know as soon as I am home. right now, I've gotta run.

Comment: Here's how you can invoke Google Apps on Android device: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html though, the following links are also a nice read.

Answer (score 1):

See [Everything you need to know about implementing iOS and Android Mobile Deep Linking](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/everything-you-need-to-know-about-implementing-ios-and-android-mobile-deep-linking-f4348b265b49). This is a good article for Android and iOS.

You may already have known that there are [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking), and starting from Android 6.0 [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) appeared. The latter are intended to open an URL only in your application, not any other competing. For instance, reddit.com can be opened in 7 applications, if not use this verification.

[image]

You can associate every needed `Activity` with links from which it should be opened. For instance, if you wish to open in the application links like `https://awesomejobs.com/jobs/{id}`, you need to add these lines to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.awesomejobsapp.ui.activity.JobActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="awesomejobs.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/jobs" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in `JobActivity` write (a code is received from an [article](https://medium.com/@1991chester/deep-links-fc993c7242af) in Russian):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.ac_job);

   final Intent intent = getIntent();
   final String action = intent.getAction();
   final String data = intent.getDataString();

   if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && data != null) {
      final String jobId = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      loadJobDetails(jobId);
   }
}
```