# How can I create a Google Sites script that detects browser type and redirects accoringly?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ios

I want to create a Google Sites script that can detect whether my visitors are using Android or iOS and then redirect them to AppStore or Google Play accordingly.
This will allow me to advertise only one QR code for all devices.
Is there a way to easily set it up and host it on Google Sites?

Answer (score 1):

Well the script needs to inspect the HTTP_USER_AGENT header, and do something like this:
[Common link to open iOS, Android and BlackBerry app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520655/common-link-to-open-ios-android-and-blackberry-app)

Bear in mind that not everyone on an Android-based device has the Google Play store (e.g. Kindle Fire -> Amazon Appstore); unfortunately getting the user to an appropriate app store on Android is tricky because there are many options.

Comment: How can I make this work on Google Sites? Is there a dummies explanation?