# How do I open any app from my web browser (Chrome) in Android? What do I have to do with the A Href link?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web

I want to open third party apps from my web browser. So, I don't have any manifest file or anything.

I have a web page.

I want to have a link which opens the third party app e.g Twitter or Opera.

How do I structure the anchor link to go open that app?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Custom URL to open App like in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065982/android-custom-url-to-open-app-like-in-ios)

Comment: @GrahamBorland I think it is significantly different

Answer (score 37):

The basic syntax for an intent based URI is as follows:

```
intent:
   HOST/URI-path // Optional host
   #Intent;
      package=[string];
      action=[string];
      category=[string];
      component=[string];
      scheme=[string];
   end;
```

Parsing details available in the [Android source](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/content/Intent.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base#6514).

To launch the ZXing barcode scanner app you can encode your href as follows:

```html
<p>
  <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end">Take a qr code</a><br>

  <a href="intent://scan/?ret=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end">Take a qr code = 10px x 10px</a><br>

  <a href="intent:play/?mediaset=android-phone-rtmp-high&amp;playlisturl=http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/playlist/bbc_one_london#Intent;scheme=bbcmediaplayer;package=air.uk.co.bbc.android.mediaplayer;end">Launch BBC</a>
</p>
```

The [Android manifest](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/AndroidManifest.xml#L93) defines the scheme to be `zxing`, the package to be `com.google.zxing.client.android` and the host data to be `scan`.

If the activity you are invoking via an intent contains `extra` data, these too can be included.

Only activities that have category filter [`android.intent.category.BROWSABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE) are able to be invoked using this method as it indicates that the application is safe to open from the browser.

Comment: maybe i'm wrong, but somehow i'm missing a reference to https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents ;)

Comment: How can the browser get the barcode scanned by ZXing?

Comment: If you want to get the code back when the scanner call the return URL, in the return (or callback) URL you have to add a placeholder with the text "{RAWCODE} . For instance http://www.example.com/scan.html?code={CODE} . The scanner app will call back to that URL with the {CODE} replaced with the actual code. The rest is up to you. Hope it help someone

Comment: @Kinlan I read your blog about this.  Do you have downloadable source I can run to test invoking intents from a browser?

Comment: @Kinlan I'm trying to pass a URL (https://example.com/path) as the URI-path/HOST. What should the format of my URI be in this case? I tried `intent://example.com/path#Intent;...;end` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is not generically possible. If other apps have a custom URL handler then you can open that URL, but otherwise you can't.