# Start app with android chrome, first time download it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

If the app is in my phone, it will start it,but if it's not, download it.
here is the code:

```
window.location = 'intent://' + schemeUrl + '#Intent;scheme=' + scheme + ';end';
            setTimeout(function() {
                self._gotoDownload(startTime);
            }, self.openTime);
```

It works well in other browsers, but'in chrome, if my phone has not install this app,it will open a error page.I try to use iframe to load the 'intent...', but it still not work.

Comment: my idea is:
window.location = 'intent://' + schemeUrl + '#Intent;scheme=' + scheme + ';end';
setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "http://www....."
        }, 3000);

Comment: anyone help to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well,after so many days,there is still nobody give me the answer.But I found the answer just now. See the[open an app in chrome in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554029/how-do-i-open-any-app-from-my-web-browser-chrome-in-android-what-do-i-have-to)

works well in my test, thanks.

Comment: It just work when my phone has installed the app,if not ,it still not work.
Anyone can solve this?