# Android: Set window.location with JS

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome-app, deep-linking

Reference: [How do I open any app from my web browser (Chrome) in Android? What do I have to do with the A Href link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554029/how-do-i-open-any-app-from-my-web-browser-chrome-in-android-what-do-i-have-to)

```html
<p>
  <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end">Take a qr code</a><br>
</p>
```

If a user clicks on the link using Android Chrome, then it opens the barcode scanner app. But if I set ***window.location = "intent url"*** it doesn't open the barcode scanner app.

```
intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end
```

Does Chrome not allow this? Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: You must do it inside a touch event (otherwise Chrome will log a warning message)

Comment: @SimonMarquis thank you. How can I trigger a touch event?

Comment: It corresponds to a user action, you can't fake that behavior

Comment: $('#link')[0].click(); works for http links. but for fb://profile or intent://, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can use [implicit intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

A good tutorial can be found [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/android-handle-custom-protocol-urls/). You can open any custom protocol urls like below, it may be not only chrome, but any mobile browsers.

> example://SomeHostPrefix/?UserName=abcdef&SessionId=12345

[image]

However, you cannot open **arbitrary Apps**, the app must have declared something in its manifest file:

[image]

Comment: for example the implicit intent, fb://profile, doesn't work with window.location.

Comment: Well, I have mentioned that if a user clicks on the link (anchor tag) using Android Chrome, then it opens the barcode scanner app. But it doesn't work, if I set window.location = "intent url", when the page loads.