# How to Launch an app from browser link using Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentfilter

i'm very new on Android development.

i have a kotlin meeting app with meetingCode and meetingtoken String to initiate a meeting.

I want to recieve this Strings value from browser link contains meetingCode and meetingtoken parameter.

I want to know how can we use intent in this scenerio to start the meeting using this parameters?

For example something on website and other on kotlin app to recieve the strings based on link

```
href="intent:#Intent;action=com.appopenfromweb.example;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;S.msg_from_browser=Launched%20from%20Browser;end">Click this link to launch you app from web
```

So When anyone clicks on the link the meeting will start in App

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open any app from my web browser (Chrome) in Android? What do I have to do with the A Href link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554029/how-do-i-open-any-app-from-my-web-browser-chrome-in-android-what-do-i-have-to)

Comment: Yes i checked it but its for third party app using barcode. i checked this example on the web wanna kind of something similar i can apply for my solution
https://mobikul.com/launch-application-browser-android/

Comment: In other words i just need a way to simply pass meetingCode & meetingToken parameter using the link to start the meeting function:
`fun startMeeting(context: Context,   meetingCode: String, meetingToken:String)`

Comment: I believe it does what you want to do. Just define your intent in you application manifest and when the application is installed on the device, your activity will be responsible for a url that you define, this url can contain some parameter that can be decoded further into extra (inside your activity onCreate function). So What is the problem?

Comment: You can not just call a function from browser and pass your argument. To do this you need an activity which will be started (so onCreate will be called here) and the argument in the form of query string will be translated into extra and you can receive them by getExtra in your onCreate function.

Comment: Thanks. Okay will try it