# Open link in google meet app from BROWSER

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, hyperlink, google-meet

I am trying to open a google meet link form chrome. But it is only opening the store page even thought the `google meet` app is installed. I tried using the following :

```
<a href="gmeet://abc-defg-hij" id="open-meet"><a/>
```

Is there any fix for this. if yes, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
<a href="https://meet.google.com/meeting-code" >Link</a>
```

Comment: but, in android an ios, it open the store app.. i need to open the code in the GoogleMeet app

Comment: Ok. Check this thread it might be helpful for you [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554029/how-do-i-open-any-app-from-my-web-browser-chrome-in-android-what-do-i-have-to)