# How "Musixmatch" knows what YouTube is playing?

Tags: android, youtube

I want to know how Musixmatch which is a music player with lyrics knows what youtube is playing. Musixmatch shows lyrics of the video which is playing in youtube. Any idea?

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607354/android-intercept-youtube-intents) it might help you.

Comment: Learn about audio fingerprinting: https://ehikioya.com/audio-fingerprinting-how-shazam-works/

Comment: Can you post more information, like a youtube url with this feature, and or any needed meta data, or web developer console error or warning messages?