# Android:open app from browser

Tags: android-manifest

I need to open the my application from browser when some pattern matching url come,I have implement using [Intercepting links from the browser to open my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app) .It is used for url only can it possible to open the app.I want to app when browser find the string like appname://id=102.

Thank you.

EDIT: please check out this code that i have use

```
<intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                 <data 
                  android:scheme="appname"
                />      
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an intent filter for an activity that contains a data tag. In the data tag you can set the scheme that you want to listen for. Something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="appname" />
</intent-filter>
```