# android respond to url without activity

Tags: android, url, browser

I have an app that is devided in Frontend and Backend. (little like MVC).
My app uses a special url scheme like "testscheme".
When the user clicks on a testscheme:// Link I want to inform the backend and the backend should set the internal state and launch an matching activity.

[Intercepting links from the browser to open my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app)
and 
[How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android/2448531#2448531) cover part of my problem but not quite.
They both point me to add a `<intent-filter>` to the `<activity>` I want to react to the scheme. But at this point I don't know what Activity to start and even if I would format my urls in a way that this would be unique I want to save the internal state before starting the Activity.

My first try was using a broadcastReciever with the very same `<intent-filter>` but this did not work.

This is the relevant part of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testurls"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <receiver android:name=".backend.BackendController" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="testurls" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the part of my receiver

```
package com.example.testurls.backend;

public class BackendController extends BroadcastReceiver implements BackendControllerInterface, GameStateLoadedListener, UrlsLoadedListener {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri data = intent.getData();    
    if(data.getHost()=="maillink"){
        this.proceedlevel();
        this.frontend.MailReturned();
    }else if(data.getHost()=="level1finished"){
        this.proceedlevel();
        this.frontend.level1Finished();
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: post your solution using broadcastreciever, this is the correct way, you just need help in implementation.

Comment: I just updated the OP with details about my implementation.