# How to grab the youtube url and play in my app?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, intentfilter

I've been searching fort this from last 2 days, but sorry to say i've not got any satisfied answers.
My question is whenever a Youtube url is clicked in android device it should list my app as **Complete action using** I've tried a lot but not getting it.
Here is the code i've tried.

```
 <intent-filter>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

     <data android:scheme="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#scheme

Comment: I've checked all things but nothing worked to me.

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app?

Comment: Ya sorry but not got any results

Comment: There is no need to sorry, the answer is in previous link, to be more specific http://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/1970317. Good luck.

Comment: Ya same answer i've tested but my app is not listed in complete using action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. Hope this will help some one else.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*.youtube.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/watch"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="*.youtube.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/watch"
                android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:host="www.youtube.com/watch?v=" android:scheme="http" ></data>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: @Sridhar are you putting this code between the <activity>...</activity> tag?

Comment: @Sridhar if you are trying the code in emulator I suggest try the code once in a real device

Comment: In real device also i've tested now.. but not working