# Open specific activity from url

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I want open specific activity my app android after click url my website from browser android.

if my url =     `<a href="http://myapp.com/aa-bb-cc-dd.html"> open activity </a>`

and my activity is **DetailActivity** , how to open this activity after click my url ?

and I want "**aa-bb-cc-dd**" for setText Textview in DetailActivity .

text1.setText("**aa**"); text2.setText("**bb**"); text3.setText("**cc**"); text4.setText("dd");

How its work?

Comment: have you tried to to use a webView?

Comment: no, i want activity without webView, but i will like >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app

but how if implement with my url ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, declare that your `DetailActivity` can handle the URL.

```
<activity
    android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSER" />
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="myapp.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can then open up the URL as usual.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://myapp.com/aa-bb-cc.html"));
startActivity(intent);
```

In your `DetailActivity`, you can get and parse the URL passed to it as follows.

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String path = uri.getPath();
```