# How to handle Google Map marker click?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, maps

I have created Google Map with multiple marker dynamically using Database,now can anybody suggested me how to create click event each of marker individually?

Comment: What are the events that you are planning to perform on click of the marker? Are all the same with small changes? Are they like opening an Activity of your app?

Comment: I want to open a new activity on each marker click event which will be displayed as a dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
private Marker marker1;
    marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(-31.952854, 115.857342))
                    .title("Title");
            marker1.setTag(0);

     mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

and in implementation of listener

```
 @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
       //marker.getTag()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Multiple markers:

First make your app to implement GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener Then create a Marker array :

```
Marker[] marker = new Marker[20]; //change length of array according to you
```

then inside

```
onMapReady(){
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
for(int i = 0 ; i < yourMarkerListsize ; i++ ) {
        marker[i] = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(list(i).getLat(), list(i).getLon())
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .title(title)
        .snippet(snippet)
        .icon(yourIcon));
    }
```

then finally

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
   //you can get assests of the clicked marker
   return false;
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for suggest me , but I need a C# code using Xamarin not Java, Its a java code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Xamarin code for the this, following is how you do it

```
GoogleMaps  Gmap;                                              

GMap.MarkerClick += GMap_MarkerClick;
GMap.InfoWindowClick += GMap_InfoWindowClick;

private void GMap_MarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Marker marker = e.Marker;
        marker.ShowInfoWindow();
    }
private void GMap_InfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

this is how you handle both marker and marker info window click events in xamarin Android Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but your code is only one marker value, which is I already have done. using below code-
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(latlng).SetTitle(dt.Rows[i]["rating"].ToString() + ": Click to request");
                                GMap.AddMarker(options);
                                GMap = googleMap;

Comment: So you want a code to insert multiple markers i suppose!? @PrashantBhatt

Comment: Yes, there are multiple markers in our google map screen, and we want individual marker click event for all markers. The markers positions are set from database and they are displayed on map using a FOR loop.

Comment: Bro its very simple all you have to do is use the marker.tag property and assign it a unique id like some primary key in your for loop then what you can do is in your marker click event get the details of the clicked marker like this  Marker marker = e.Marker; and get the clicked marker

Answer (score 0):

I think the below approach may help you:

As others have said, you can set an `OnMarkerClickListener` to the marker, to perform an event on Marker click and add launch activity using an URL, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21471110/2414073). 
So you can store the activity url also in DB.
When dynamically creating the marker, maintain a Map whose key will be object of `Marker` class and Value will be `String` the URL.

so, inside `onMarkerClick()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
   String activityUrl = markerURLMap.get(marker);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(activityUrl));
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to attach unique URLs per marker click, you need to attach an object that you tag within Marker.Tag as follows:

```
UrlObject url = new UrlObject()
                {
                    Url = "enteryoururlhere"
                };
marker.Tag = UrlObject;
```

Then, you would get your URL that is unique to each marker by calling the following:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        UrlObject obj = marker.Tag;
        String activityUrl = obj.Url;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse(activityUrl));
        startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Your UrlObject class would be easy to setup:

```
    class UrlObject : Java.Lang.Object
    {
          public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit: You would make a tag for every marker in your loop. That way, when each marker is created, it is tagged properly with each url.