# Using Intent filter for inter process communication

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I want to enable my application to be called from different applications by using urls or sort of rest enablement, such that different actions in my application can be performed by the different clients.

For e.g. there is action "a" which helps the user to navigate to a particular screen in my application.

I am planning to use it using urls it can be custom schemes or http. I have already read the debates between custom schemes and http schemes :).

So for e.g if a client calls `mysite.com://a?queryParam=1&queryParam=2` then depending on the action `"a"` and query params i am navigating to particular screen.

I am using intent filters here for inter process communication. Then i will write a url handler depending on the type of action. Action type can be derived from the last path segment of the query. .Fetching of query parameters can be done through `uri.getQueryParameters`. Is using the intent filter and URI apis right for this kind of scenarios ?.

I had read about AIDL which can be used for inter process communication, but that is very tightly bound and client has to know lot of information about the provider or my application. i somehow want the rest type enablement of my application.

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understood the request, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/1354302) seems a good one for you.

This allow you to intercept all `Intent`s with the `android.intent.action.VIEW` action, but only those that match your `URI`. So if the user clicks on a link with matching url scheme he will have to choose the application to open it (browser or your app). Once you have the `Intent` you can analize it and take your actions.

Comment: Yes..so it seems my approach looks fine