# Responding to URL other than Google

Tags: android

I use the answer from [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent) for responding to URL. However, it just works for Google. When I change the host in manifest, it doesn't work. How to use another URL?

Comment: change the host address to the URL you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN INTENT FILTER CHANGE THE HOST TO YOUR HOST URL

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: TRY THIS -->   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app