# Opening android app from browser: How to specify URI-path/HOST in intent URI?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to open an android app from the browser. I also want to pass a specific host URL (`https://example.com/mypath`) to the intent.

My app already has an intent-filter that I'm referencing here.

I'm using the following intent URI to open the app.

```
intent://example.com/mypath#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;package=my_package;action=my_action;end"
```

But this doesn't work. Is this the correct way to write the host URL in the intent-URI?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25524407/43702790) ?

Comment: @theapache64 I can't do that because the host url isn't constant. It's a variable string in the browser code.