# how to open android application from my website

Tags: android, web-services, webview, web

I have a website it has many links like Facebook , Twitter and etc.
when some one click that facebook link in android browser , it should open facebook android app , if it is installed in that device otherwise i should open google market.

so how to give my

```
`<a href="what link should i give here?" >open facebook</a>



<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

if i give this link play store opening, same way how to open other app?

```
 <a href="market://details?id=com.linkedin.android">clikc me </a>
```

this link brings me to market place , instead of this i want to open linked app directly

Comment: check out this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through adding `intent filter` to your `activity`

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my_new_app" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, in your web app you can put links like:

```
<a href="my_new_app://other/parameters/here">
```

Additionally, if you want to extract URI params in your activity from the URL you clicked

```
List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
String first = params.get(0); // "other"
String second = params.get(1); // "parameters"
String third = params.get(2); // "here"
```

Comment: what is mean by "my_new_app"? i'm not using android codes in my website

Comment: these are called `schemes`, my_new_app is scheme, you can put your app name as scheme. Whatever you like

Comment: should i give the package name there?

Comment: dude , i'm not creating any android app. i'm creating a website. from that website i should open android app.

Comment: you have to put in that your app and your website. otherwise nto possible.

Comment: dude, if i dont know the shemes of an app , how to findout know that? <a href="facebook://"> like this

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but try this link ...

```
facebook://facebook.com/inbox

com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity

com.facebook.katana
```

Comment: it is not working , it takes me to website link  facebook://facebook.com/inbox and shows webpage is not available

Answer (score 0):

**You can't open just any app**. The web-browser they're using has to interpret the link and decides what to do with it.

For example Chrome for android annoyingly "google searches" `localhost/` when you bang that into it's address bar, it decides you want to search rather than literally go to `http://localhost/`

It will in turn **open up native apps it's aware of if it's familiar with the link provided**
I only know of the market link `market://search?q=pname:com.google.earth` which will open the market and take you to the Google earth app. I don't know what would trigger the facebook app to open though sorry. *This link goes nowhere in Chrome for Desktop PC however*