# When I am in a browser and I click on a link I want see my app in an action list and I go to the link using my app

Tags: android

Consider we have a link as follows in a `html` file.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/link.html/"> Link </a> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

I want when I am in a browser and I click the above link, first I see my application in a action list and when I click on the my application on the action list I go to the link by my application. I have a simple `webView` class that it is made of the an activity in my application.

Comment: Take a look at this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You would have to put IntentFilter in manifiest

```
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <data android:scheme="http"/> 
          </intent-filter>
```