# How to force a link to open with a particular app in android using javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube

Am trying to force open a link with the particular using javascript.How can I do that. Unable to find it.Just I want the below link to be opened with youtube app but its been redirected to the home page in browser.

```
   <html>
      <head>
   <script>
      window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?                  
         v=hVSdReP8b14&list=PLE7ufOKMDsey6rNilV0rlZzb8vdFj6dFL&index=1";
  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>welcome</p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

This answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/7173701

for more information https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Comment: the links are related links in app but i need to keep in my mobile website basically html and css