# How to handle an Action View Intent inside my own app

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

Sorry if this should already have been asked, but Google didn't give me anything of that sort.

I would like to extend the capabilities of an in-app browser of mine to handle also links from other apps, so I guess I would need to handle Action_View intents. But after having searched it, I didn't find any ways of getting the URL of such an intent nor any other information on how to procede.

Might anyone help me here?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent

Comment: @Rasi No, what I would like to do is that other apps can open which ever web site in the app, making it a web browser for all apps:)

Comment: you can't force any App to get open in your App, but with the help of intent filters you can make your App eligible to handle Urls.

Comment: @Rasi I don't want to force any apps. I would like to make it eligible. Could you show me how?:)

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combined with code of the Lightning browser in the Android manifest found my solution. Thanks!

[Intercepting links from the browser to open my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app)