# How to make external web link open in app?

Tags: android, webview, web

I am recently trying to develop an app for my website. Suppose if I share the url of any article of my web site through Whatsapp or Facebook and if I click on it I want it to open in my app and not in the external browser.

For example: If you have the Facebook app, any link with 'www.facebook.com/.....' opens in the app only.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, what about this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/4862968

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercepting links from the browser to open my Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/2002343

Google is your best friend