# Intercepting links from Facebook app to open my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app), I have managed to intercept link from Google search result to open my app, but is there any way I can intercept link from Facebook app to open my app? At current stage, clicking on the link only open my webpage in Facebook's build in browser and not my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using app linking (not deeplinking, but similar). You have to provide meta tags to your hosted website. Refer this link
https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/

. You have to provide your package name and fb app id to the meta tags, and you will be redirected to your app.

Comment: i don't see how this will open my app rather than showing the webpage normally in Facebook's built in browser

Comment: Just go to the fb developer site and search for meta tags as well as applinking. You'll get the answer. https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Remember, it might take some time to actually work. So you better do some crawling through the developer site to see if it works.

Comment: the debugging tool doesn't tell me if the link will open an app or not?

Comment: You can verify that link, if it contains your fb app id or not..After web crawling, try sharing the same link in fb privately to see if it works.