# Set default browser flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a mobile browser app. When you download a browser from the play market, then a notification pops up "Which browser do you want to use by default?". How to do it?

Update:
I added this filter to `AndroidManifest.xml` file. And now, when you click on a link in any application, it asks through which browser to open the link, but now how to intercept this link to send it to the webview? [As here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609662/16864379)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.speech.action.VOICE_SEARCH_RESULTS" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:scheme="about" />
    <data android:scheme="javascript" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:scheme="inline" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Read about how to send push/local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this package** [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) 
**example code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:receive_sharing_intent/receive_sharing_intent.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late StreamSubscription _intentDataStreamSubscription;
  String? _sharedText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory
    _intentDataStreamSubscription =
        ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((String value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedText = value;
        print("Shared: $_sharedText");
      });
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getLinkStream error: $err");
    });

    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is closed
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((String? value) {
      setState(() {
        _sharedText = value;
        print("Shared: $_sharedText");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _intentDataStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textStyleBold = TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text("Shared urls/text:", style: textStyleBold),
              Text(_sharedText ?? "")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```