# Use URL to show new activity?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, webview

Inside my app, I was wondering if it was possible to make a certain URL in a WebView, when clicked, to redirect to a new activity view outside of the WebView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monitor events in a `WebView` using a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).  The method you want is [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)).  This allows you to perform your own action when a particular URL is selected.

You set the `WebViewClient` of your `WebView` using the [`setWebViewClient()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)).

Alternatively, you could [use a specific `Intent` filter to "hijack" particular URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent).  I think if you use this approach:

- The user will have to confirm that they want to use your Activity for the URLs
- It will hijacks these URLs from other applications too.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out this **[link](http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/#awp::2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/)** you will see an example of an Intent Filter being defined to launch an Activity. The website is set to call the callback URL when the user is done authenticating. This in turn gets handled by the browser and launches the Activity with the appropriate Intent Filter.