# Android intent not working to make app launcheable from browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to achieve this using the following code:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="ttest" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Clicking 'debug' on Eclipse will launch my app correctly. But going to the browser and typing 'ttest://foo' won't launch the app as expected. What's wrong?

Comment: If you add `android:host="*"` to the `data` tag, does that solve the issue?

Comment: @Eric it does not work... when I type "ttest://foo" on the Android browser, it goes to google search, even after (I think) installing the app with that intent-filter, by clicking debug on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests on an HTC Sensation running ICS, a Samsung running 2.3.3, and a 4.0.3 emulator.  I couldn't get any URL intent handling to work on the HTC, but had no trouble with the Samsung or the emulator.  Any chance you're using an HTC phone?  Apparently HTCs have a problem with this: [Standard intent URI broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780090/standard-intent-uri-broken)