# Link from Android browser to my application not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I want from the android browser be able to launch my application if it's installed, or launch my website in the other case.
So in order to make it work, I put :

```
<activity android:name=".MMLogin" android:label="MeetMe" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="meet-me.com" android:path="/signin" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>    
</activity>
```

in the *Manifest*, and I created a dummy link to test; and it's not working.

- I've tried with and without: BROWSABLE and DEFAULT
- I've tried with meetme://datas and change the scheme; nothing worked.

I used threads on stackoverflow like :
[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

What am I doing wrong, or is there a special thing to do to make it work ? 
My application suppports from API 7.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used :
[Intent Filter to Launch My Activity when custom URI is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596261/intent-filter-to-launch-my-activity-when-custom-uri-is-clicked), I think what was missing is this block :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```