# iOS OpenUrl Equivalent in Android

Tags: android, ios, browser, openurl

Is there a way to implement OpenUrl functionality(as in iOS OpenUrl) in android?

for example,
If a user is redirected from a webpage(in a browser) to "`myapp://main`",
android will launch my app.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is just to add this to manifest inside the activity you want to start  :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.dimrix.something.BootActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>


         <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="SomeScheme" />
            <data android:scheme="otherScheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

and than if you write inside the browser

SomeScheme://

or

otherScheme://

it will start the activity....

you can even send info after the scheme if you want to do action according to the url by getting the intent data in the activity

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
```

so you can write

SomeScheme://water

and respond to the "water" as you like with the Uri data .

Answer (score 1):

Define a **[Custom URL Scheme](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120393/custom-url-scheme---iphone--android)**, for example to open your SplashScreen Activity when a user type in the browser `myapp://main`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myapp.SplashScreen"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- URL scheme -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host=main" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!--URL scheme -->
</activity>
```

More info:

- **[Add an Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html#AddIntentFilter)**
- **[Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)**

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with Intent Filters.

See [Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) in the Android documentation, or answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596261/intent-filter-to-launch-my-activity-when-custom-uri-is-clicked).