# Android, open url by my application

Tags: java, android

I have my custom website where my android app will get data.

Lets call it `example.com`.

My android app can share links via other applications like WhatsApp. When link is shared, it creates link like `http://example.com/my/path/to/information`.

I want to open my own application when this link is clicked. In my `AndroidManifest` file I have added these lines of code for my intent:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/.*" android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

My Activity handles its intent like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Log.d("My_intent", intent.toString());
mainNewsId = intent.getStringExtra("news_info");
Log.d("News_result", mainNewsId);
```

When I use other applications where link is shared and click it, it must suggest to me applications that can open this link.

However, **it does not suggest my application that shared this link**.

What did I miss? Do I need to add `meta` tags to my webpage for android?

**========================UPDATE=================================**

I have found an interesting outcome. In my intent filter, if I write on `android:host` some other popular site, which has its own android app, it **suggests to open my applcation along with its own application when I click to link**.

Does it mean that I need to write something in my webpage?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596261/intent-filter-to-launch-my-activity-when-custom-uri-is-clicked

Comment: Are you mentioning any activity that should handle your  intent filter?

Comment: Yes. This intent filter is inside handling activity. Problem is when I click to link in my other app. It suggests to open it by my browsers but does not suggest my application.

Comment: add your code where you suggest to open the link.

Comment: Did you try without giving the pathPattern

Comment: This work for me check this it will you or someone else later on
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781149/app-link-not-working-for-facebook-on-android/40781465#40781465

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using these methods.

In my web page, I have added `link` tags to `head`:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.example.app/example.com/my/path/to/information"/>
```

In my manifest, I have added this:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
   <data android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/.*" android:scheme="http"/>
   <data android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/.*" android:scheme="https"/>
   <data android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/.*" android:scheme="android-app"/>
   <data android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This worked. Now when I click to links it suggests my application to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing specific path prefixes. 
For example if you wish to open `http://example.com/my/path/to/information` then intent filter should look like this

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/my/" android:scheme="http"/>
```

Then if you wish to open the same activity with different path prefixes, you will need to add a data tag for each prefix.

Comment: Tried. My phone does not suggest my app to open this link.