# How to launch an activity from browser in android?

Tags: android, browser, intentfilter

How can I launch my activity from android browser?

I have a link say,http://a.b.com. I need to open activity when user enters that URL in android browser. I have the following intent filters in my android manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="a.b.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>  
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Is your `<intent-filter>` inside your `<activity android:name="MyActivity">`?

Comment: I´d like to know how to start an activity with android:scheme="http", i tried before with no success!:(

Comment: when i tried this i found the browser still in the view stack , how can i remove it from the view stack ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [How to register some URL namespace (myapp://app.start/) for accessing your program by calling a URL in browser in Android OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430045/)

(Don't get stuck at the title of the question.  The answers are relevant.)

Comment: I have searched for the answer on Internet  and everyone states that all you need to do is just give intent filter in manifest. But even though O had given it I'm not getting the result. When I type the URL in browser it doesn't launches my app....

Comment: Same here. I am using the exact code as you, but it doesnt work. I too, read multiple articles, posts, threads and they all say, the above code is what we need. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This example launch my activity from android browser and display first 2 GET prams form URL

```
package com.example.openapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        try{
            Uri data = getIntent().getData();
            if(data != null){
                String scheme = data.getScheme(); 
                String host = data.getHost();
                List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
                String first = params.get(0); 
                String second = params.get(1);
                txt1.setText(first);
                txt2.setText(second);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
        }       
    }
}
```

You need to add this in manifest and replace android host with your host:

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.openapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```