# Android - How to Interact with Android app while from Web Browsers?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, opera

I'm developing an Android Application in which I need to Interact the web browser(Like chrome,Opera ) with my android app.

That is, In Android Device , when I click my particular web URL using any of the browsers. The App must be opened .

I'm really Confusing with this task .
Please anybody help me by reply me How to achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are many links which can help you with that. See

1. [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)
2. [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)
3. [Invoke android application from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480559/invoke-android-application-from-browser?rq=1)
4. [Open my Android app from URL link from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207073/open-my-android-app-from-url-link-from-browser)
5. [How to launch an activity from browser in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732693/how-to-launch-an-activity-from-browser-in-android?rq=1)

Hope they help you understanding how to do it. If there is any specific issue you are facing, I would be happy to help further.

Comment: Thanks, Shobhit Puri .I tried this . I works fine . But when I click that URL ,the Dialog with my app opened along with other installed browsers.But I need to show my app only .How to do that ?