# About starting Android app from an URL

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to figure out how to start an app from a URL, and how I should write that URL.

I have the following code in my AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:host="my.app" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I used a URL as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430045/how-to-register-some-url-namespace-myapp-app-start-for-accessing-your-progra/2430468#5651246), but nothing happens.

Please let me know if my intent is well written, and how I should write the URL that calls that app, and note that I need to call my "Main" Activity.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have two `<intent-filter>` elements for this `<activity>`. One will be for `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER`. The other will be for `VIEW`, `BROWSABLE`/`DEFAULT`, and your `<data>` element:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:host="my.app" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, `http://my.app` should launch your activity.

Comment: thx for your comment, but this doesn't work for me. I tried writing that URL in the browser, but my app doesn't start.

Comment: @FelipeDev: Here is a sample project demonstrating this technique: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler

Comment: @FelipeDev: and here is a URL to a page that you can visit in your browser that invokes links that will launch that application: http://commonsware.com/sample

Comment: thx a lot! It takes me a couple of minutes trying to find aout the URL trick. I mean, I can have a page with the link to my app and if I click it, my app get started, but I cant copy/paste the same link in the browser to try open the app. Anyway, your answer solve my problem. Thx man!

Comment: In my case, this works in my HTC Butterfly's browser, and works in Firefox for android, but didn't work on Chrome for android...

Comment: Something I've found is that if the url you're using has a path component, but your intent filter doesn't contain an android:path section, it won't be picked up.

Comment: Ok and if someone knows how to launch an app in separate sandbox? When I launch my app from browser in starts on top of the browser. I need something like launchig apps from Play Market on Open button click, but with url links

Comment: It starts within the same app from which it was opened ? is that a bug ?

Comment: When I'm using two intent filters, two separate instances of app gets created, one when I click on icon to launch the app, and one when I click the url.  How do I prevent that from happening.