# Android,start Activity by urlspan with extras?

Tags: android, android-activity, urlspan

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7417688/1043882),we can start Activity by Intent that is created with specific url,when Activity has desired intent filter.So we can start Activity by setting a `URLSpan` for SpanableString that is set as text for text view,like this:

```
ss.setSpan(new URLSpan("http:my.Activity"), 13, 17,
                   Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

When we use an Intent to start Activity,we can add more details as `extras` to intent and retrieve them in Activity by `getExtras` method.My question is:

Is there any way to start Activity by `URLSpan` and also send a String which can be retrieved by target Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, extend URLSpan and override its onClick method

Comment: Yes,it is OK.But I do not want to extend URLSpan.

Comment: well, what can i say, if you dont want to do that your problem will not be solved