# Make HTML anchor links start a new activity in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I have a String that contains HTML tags which I display in a `TextView`

```
Spanned text;
String htmlText = "<p dir=\"ltr\">It was a great day with <a href=\"52\">Julius</a> and <a href=\"18\">Stanley</a></p>";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    text = Html.fromHtml(htmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
else
    text = Html.fromHtml(htmlText);

textView.setText(text);
```

Now I want those links to be clickable, and not just clickable, but to startup an Activity when clicked. The `href` attributes have numbers which I want to pass as a parameter to my `Intent` to start my Activity.

I use `JSoup` to extract the values of the `href` like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlText, "UTF-8");
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
for(int e = 0; e < elements.size(); e++){
    Element element = elements.get(e);
    String href = element.attr("href");
}
```

So I was hoping I can get a `ClickEventListener` on the links and start the activity like this:

```
element.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
        Bundle userParams = new Bundle();
        userParams.putString("userId", href);
        intent.putExtras(userParams);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

I know `element` is not a `ViewGroup` so it can't be done like my code shows, but is there any possible way of achieving this?

Comment: Try the suggested answer to [SO: Opening android activity with a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191021/android-open-activity-when-a-url-was-clicked) and take a look at [deeplinks](https://www.raywenderlich.com/18330247-deep-links-in-android-getting-started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search and I got an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19989677/5585069)

```
String htmlText = "<p dir=\"ltr\">It was a great day with <a href=\"52\">Julius</a> and <a href=\"18\">Stanley</a></p>";
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(htmlText);
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);   
for(URLSpan span : urls) {
    makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span);
}
textView.setText(strBuilder);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And then the `makeLinkClickable` method to handle the links

```
protected void makeLinkClickable(SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span){
    int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String href span.getURL();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
            Bundle userParams = new Bundle();
            userParams.putString("userId", href);
            intent.putExtras(userParams);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
    strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}
```