# Exception when using Linkify to access an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, linkify

I'm getting an exception while trying to launch an Activity on clicking a `textview`.
Here is code am using to access the activity

```
tv1.setText(result+"  ");
                tv1.setEms(5);
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z/a-zA-Z]");
                Linkify.addLinks(tv1, pattern,null);  
                tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Http_schedule.this, HttpSecondSchedule.class);                    
                        try {
                            ourIntent.putExtra("Voyage", (String)jo.get("Voyage"));
                            ourIntent.putExtra("Ship", jo.get("Ship").toString());
                            startActivity(ourIntent);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                tbrow2.addView(tv1);
```

Here is the android.manifest file where I registered my second activity

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HttpSecondSchedule"
        android:label="Seat Availability" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ship_service_list.HttpSecondSchedule" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the error am getting

```
12-05 08:16:38.600: E/InputEventReceiver(1458): Exception dispatching input event.
12-05 08:16:38.600: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1458): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-05 08:16:38.770: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1458): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=v (has extras) }
12-05 08:16:38.770: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1458):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
12-05 08:16:38.770: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1458):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
```

]

Comment: are you using `NDK`? The error seems come from `JNI`

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z/a-zA-Z]");
     //Linkify.addLinks(tv1, pattern,null);            I did this and the error disappeared ... Is there any alternatives to this.

Comment: Can atleast some one say how to call activity using Linkify.. am new to android some one help

Comment: You may need to update your question based on your need, i already added `linkify` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Http_schedule.this, HttpSecondSchedule.class);                    
       try {
             ourIntent.setAction("com.example.ship_service_list.HttpSecondSchedule");
              ourIntent.putExtra("Voyage", (String)jo.get("Voyage"));
              ourIntent.putExtra("Ship", jo.get("Ship").toString());
              startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to have two  elements for this . One
>   will be for MAIN and LAUNCHER. The other will be for VIEW,
>   BROWSABLE/DEFAULT, and your  element:
>
> `` <activity android:name=".MyActivity">
>       <intent-filter>`
>           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
>       </intent-filter>
>       <intent-filter>
>           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
>           <data android:host="my.app" android:scheme="http"></data>
>       </intent-filter>
>   </activity> ``
>
> Then, http://my.app should launch your activity.
>
> --https://stackoverflow.com/a/7417688/1815624