# URL scheme not working in android browser

Tags: android, url-scheme

I need my application opens when clicking on a link. for this I read that I must use a URL scheme. The link must have the form myapp://parameters.

I read every post on this subject, but when I send an email with "myapp://addUser/?id=22" and I open from chrome (on my phone), it is not clickable.

My manifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="com.example"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

My class:

public class SplashActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String id = uri.getQueryParameter("id"); 
    }

}
```

Content of the mail to test the code:

```
myapp://addUser/?id=22
```

Reference Links:

[Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228)

[How to register some URL namespace (myapp://app.start/) for accessing your program by calling a URL in browser in Android OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430045/how-to-register-some-url-namespace-myapp-app-start-for-accessing-your-progr/2430468#2430468)

https://legacy.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/custom-url-scheme-primarily-android-3

**UPDATE**

I think the problem is the mail body, but I don't know how I can test this.

Answer (score 3):

In your manifest

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="com.example"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

you define android:host="com.example", so you should modify link URL :

```
myapp://addUser/?id=22       //error
myapp://com.example/?id=22   //correct
```

then it can work!!

Answer (score 1):

I made a test here and in the manifest file I just removed the "android:host" parameter, leaving this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

and it opened an URL `myapp://testing` here that I put on a simple HTML file just for trying.