# Launch an activity from browser and send data

Tags: android

I have defined an intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="bankpaid"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And I loaded the activity from the web browser like this:

`href="intent://success/#Intent;scheme=bankpaid;package=some.url;end"`

I tried to read the data sent to the activity like this:

```
protected void onStart() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.d("sharedText", sharedText);
    }
    super.onStart();
}
```

The problem is that `sharedText` turns out to be null.

How can I send data to an activity from the web and how can the activity receive that data?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4085365/4848308

Comment: @GueorguiObregon I used to be able to do something like that but since I have switched to deep app linking with Chrome, I have no idea how to do something similar.