# Start Androidapp with a link in a email

Tags: android

Hallo Developers,

is it possible to start a activity with a link from a Email like in Iphone SDK and start this aktivity with params.

Iphone example: 
Appname:///?param1=value1&param2=value2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be possible - check these other answers on stackoverflow:

[How to implement my very own URI scheme on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448213/how-to-implement-my-very-own-uri-schema-on-android/2448531#2448531)

[Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge in stock Android. However they've made a link scheme that will open up the Market application to a specific page, so this is possible. I would think however that in order to set something like that up the app you are wanting to start from link would have to be listening for clicks on that specific type of link and tell the system that it can handle them. I have no idea how you'd go about implementing that though, and it would only be able to start specific apps that were designed that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try `content://com.user.package.ActivityClass/`. I haven't tried it so I am not sure if it will work though.

See here for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html