# Is it possible to start an android activity from a hyperlink?

Tags: android

I'm building an app to integrate with a server hosted system. One of the pages on the system starts a signature capture library installed on the device with html a href="intent:#Intent;    action=biz.binarysolutions.signature.CAPTURE; followed by parameters. Once the signature is captured I need to navigate back to another activity from another hyperlink. Any advice on the best way to do this would be appreciated. I'm relatively new to android development but the rest of the project is coming together fine. I just seem to be going round in circles with this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes - that should be possible, provided your application is capable of handling the intent associated with the clicking of a URL.

**`HINT`**: that's how you get the option of choosing a browser app when you click on a link. That is, in case you have installed other browser apps as well.

Refer these previous questions - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser).

Comment: Ah, that second link looks perfect. Thank you.