# Launch an android application via web link

Tags: android

I want to launch my own application when the web link in browser is clicked.
I search a lot on internet,and the method of solving this question is similar.
But mine does't work. There is no effect when i click the web link
Is there some other things i don't notice?
Can anyone tell me where my application is wrong?Thank you

Here is my program:

the link is:
    google

URLApp.java:

```
public class URLApp extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Uri uri = intent.getData();

    Log.i("++++++++++++++++++++++", uri.getScheme().toString());
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.receiver"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".URLApp"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"></data>
            <data android:host="www.google.com"></data>
        </intent-filter>   
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Edit:
After i define my own URL scheme,the program works.
My own web link is

```
<a href="myapp://test">click me!</a>
<data android:scheme="myapp"></data>
```

Why it does not work by using android:scheme="http"
Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
<data android:host="www.YOUR-URL-HERE.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Maybe you could remove the `android:host` tag to react on all urls.

See also:
[Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

Comment: Thanks,Thomas K.I removed the android:host tag, it still does not work.Are there some settings that i should set on device itself?