# android youtube: share a youtube video TO my app?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, youtube, share

The built in YouTube App for tablets has a sharing-option. For example: I watch a video in the YouTube app and click the button to **share**. Bluetooth, Googlemail, and Dropbox appear for me. 
I wonder how i can **list my app there**? Which intent-filter has my app to have? How do i **get the video url** then?
Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This worked for me.
Add this intent filter to your manifest file to make your application appear in the share list of the youtube application.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />              
   <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then to retrieve it in your activity, use this :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Here you are!

Comment: Why the hell does this one work, but this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent) doesn't?

Comment: It works but android:scheme is missing from <data>, what should we put there?

Comment: You may add `android:scheme="http"` to `<data ` with newer versions of android. @PedroD

Comment: This answer doesn't work exclusively for YouTube, you can share any text to your Activity, if you use this `intent-filter`. I thought that this was because of the missing scheme but adding a `https` scheme removes `myApp` from the IntentChooser altogether.

Answer (score 4):

I played around a bit and ended with this solution:

```
<intent-filter android:label="My YT Handler">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:host="youtu.be" android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Youtube have changed share intent so for me only solution that works is the one I copied from android Telegram manifest. 
Solution is tested and working on Marshamallow 6.0.1 and Lolipop 5.1.1.

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```