# How to share YouTube url to my Python kivy app?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, pyjnius

I am building an `Android` App using `Python` and `kivy` (`kivymd`), and I want to let the user share a `YouTube` link directly from YouTube to my app. So when i click share on YouTube my app appears there, with all the other apps like this:
[image]

And when the user clicks it, it directs them to the app where the program saves the url into a variable, so that it can do stuff with it. How can I do this?

I found an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38589296/17895692) explaining how to do this:

```
<activity ...>
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />              
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Would i be able to somehow do this in `Python`? Im guessing maybe i could use `pyjnius`, but im not sure how.

Comment: Did you get an answer? I have a kivy app that I want to be the receiver of a photo from the gallery (share)

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3

Look at there, everything will be here or close to

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).