# Share url from Youtube iOS app to my Codename One iOS app

Tags: codenameone

I need to share a video link from the Youtube app to my Codename One app on iOS.

It seems possible, according to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036939/1277576

With Codename One, I tried to add these build hints:

```
ios.plistInject=<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key><array><dict><key>CFBundleURLName</key><string>net.informaticalibera.myappname</string></dict><dict><key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key><array><string>https</string></array></dict></array>
ios.urlScheme=<string>https</string>
```

and I added this code to a bare bones project:

```
public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }

        String url = Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", null);

        Form hi = new Form("Test case", BoxLayout.y());
        if (url != null) {
            hi.add(new SpanLabel("Intercepted URL:\n" + url));
        } else {
            hi.add(new Label("No URL was intercepted"));
        }
        hi.show();
    }
```

but it doesn't work: when I share a video link, Youtube offers me several apps, but not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also implement it in native code and I think there are also changes required to the xcode project if I remember correctly from investigating this a while back. Currently we don't have official support for this use case but you can file an RFE for that.