# "Open with" my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, wikipedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

I'm working on a Wikipedia client and I want the user to be able to open a page using my app (like the official Wikipedia app). How can this be archived?

Answer (score 0):

You going to want to use an [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) see this SO question - [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)