# Start activity from browser-link

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to start a custom activity by clicking on a browser-link (e.g. market://details?id= opens the app  in Play Store).

How can I do that?

(I hope, you understand what I want to do - sorry for my bad english)

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent

Answer (score 0):

This way you can do this

```
    <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="www.parag-chauhan.com"
                        android:path="/test"
                        android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

For more Ref - [Check Link](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2013/03/make-link-in-android-browser-start-up.html)