# Titanium: Check if application installed on the device (android)

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

How i can check if application installed on android device (for e.g. by application id - com.foo.bar) ? 
Or, how i can get list of all android application installed on the device?
Im use titanium mobile.
Thanks!

Comment: Ask the application manager?

Comment: Can you please provide example how to ask application manager from Titanium ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the all the installed applications like this..

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> appData = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            mainIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo appInfo : appData) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.setApplicationName(appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)
                .toString());
    }
```

Comment: Hm, is it code for titanium?
Looks like it's java, not titanium's javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

The code that was written here is indeed a Java code. I don't think Titanium exposes a methods that access the information you are looking for.

What you can do is write your own native Titanium Module in Java that uses that uses the code kalyanpvs wrote you and use it from within javascript.

Check this out http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide to learn more about module development for Android in titanium.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at your requirements slightly but it is possible to link a url to your app.

When you try and load that url from any source (e.g. an sms, an email) it will open the app if you have it, or else it will just open the url in your browser.

See here: [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)

Does that help at all?

Comment: No, i need to check if user installed some application.