# Cannot open my app from url

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been trying to open my app when user clicks on a link in browser. I tried to use scheme to open my app. The change I made in `Manifest` is given below.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.testapp.TestAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
           <data android:scheme="testscheme" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I also have internet permission added. However opening links like **"testscheme://testID=1**" do not open up my app. Am I missing something here? I cannot find a solution for this anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the code to TestAppActivity's `onResume()` function?

Comment: Does [this similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/525063/1051783) help?

Comment: From this It seems correct to me. I think some issue in your Activity that might closing the app. Did you debug the application?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: @CarlAnderson TestAppActivity is a simple activity with no code in onResume

Comment: @TGMCians My activity never gets called.

Comment: @DavidWasser I used the android browser that comes with device and chrome

Comment: @gunar that does not solve my issue. Its the same code as mine

Comment: Can you paste the html you're using to try to launch your app?

Comment: @glo: is this issue still not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue and I couldn't. Here's what I have: 
**A**. An activity with a very simple layout (only a `TextView`)

```
package com.test.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.adip.R;

public class TestAppActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_layout);
        TextView txtLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
        Intent startIntent = getIntent();
        Uri data = startIntent.getData();
        if (data == null) {
            txtLabel.setText("No data provided!");
        } else {
            txtLabel.setText(data.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**B** The Manifest contains what you have:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.testapp.TestAppActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="testscheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**C.** A `sample.html` file that I published on a local `Tomcat` web server.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="testscheme://testID=1">Test scheme</a> <br/>
        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Working link to SO</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When opening this file from **ANY BROWSER** both links work as:

1. The first link opens the `TestAppActivity` showing in the `TextView`: `testscheme://testID=1` - exactly what I have in html
2. The second link opens the good-old StackOverflow in the same browser.

You must be doing something wrong and it's that small you can't see it :). Maybe you have typed incorrectly the link in html file ...

Anyway, make a compare between what I have provided and what you have.