# The custom url not showing as link

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking

I want to view the content of the link **App_Name://music/tamil/album/album_id** when user clicks it from browser or gmail app.

I tried it as the following ways.
 1)

```
 <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="/music"
                    android:scheme="App_Name" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

2)

```
 <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:pathPrefix="/music"
                    android:scheme="App_Name" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

3)

```
<intent-filter >

            <data
                android:host="appname.com"
                android:pathPrefix="music"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALL_APPS"/>

        </intent-filter>
```

I composed a mail with the content as follows

appname://music/tamil/album/T0004125

www.appname://music/tamil/album/
T0004125

www.appname://music/tamil/album/T0004125

** http://appname.com/music/tamil/album/T0004125

The above list except ** not shown as link. How to make them as link to do the deep link feature in my app?

By the 3rd approach not shown the "Complete action with" when click the link. Kindly help me on this .

Comment: http://www.jayway.com/2009/09/24/the-browsable-category-revealed/

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent